# Anchor tag- not getting logs on mousedown in iphone7/6s plus

Tags: javascript, iphone, reactjs

I'm trying to log some events on my mywebsite . I added mousedown listener on my document and getting events for clicking on any element. 
I make a request on my server whenever any element is clicked.
It is working fine on Desktop browser and on the android mobile as well.
But in iphone/safari the event for anchor tag is capturing but before request is sent to server it is navigating to another page. And my log is not saving on server.

I added the listner like this :

```
   window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
console.log("mouse donwn called>>")
var { value, innerHTML, type, tagName,  } = e.target || {};
var params = {value,innerHTML, type,tagName};
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:6360/log-tracking", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(params)
  });
});
```

And my server is :

```
  app.all("/log-tracking", async (req, resp) => {
     console.log("server called>>>>>>>>");

     });
```

But for anchor tag there is no log saved in iphone6s/7.

Kindly give any suggestion regarding this.

Answer (score -1):

As  You are getting mouse down event on windows.So,here i put condition that if you have event on anchor tag that will stop redirection by prevent default and keep your log to be submitted successfully.   after getting response from log file. it will redirect page to target URL.

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {

if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a')
{
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = e.target.href; //this is the url where the anchor tag points to.
  var { value, innerHTML, type, tagName,  } = e.target || {};
  var params = {value,innerHTML, type,tagName};
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:6360/log-tracking", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
       Accept: "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(params)

   }).then(function(response) {
     window.location=url;
   });
}
else 
{ 
 console.log("mouse donwn called>>")
 var { value, innerHTML, type, tagName,  } = e.target || {};
 var params = {value,innerHTML, type,tagName};
 fetch("http://127.0.0.1:6360/log-tracking", {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
       Accept: "application/json"
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(params)
  });
}
});
```

Comment: There is no description. How will some one understand ?

Comment: Person who asked question will surely understand. but for batter understanding  i will surely add description. Thanks for respond.